# Matching arabic text with regex

Tags: java, regex, arabic

I'm trying to match only arabic text using regex but I'm getting an exception. Here's my code:

```
txt.matches("\\P{Arabic}+")
```

Here's the exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown character property name {Arabic} near index 9
\P{Arabic}+

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use  this character block

```
\p{InArabic}+
```

---

In java Unicode scripts, blocks, categories and binary properties are written with the `\p` and `\P`(negated effect)

- **Scripts** are specified either with the prefix `Is` or by using the `script` keyword([supported scripts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeScript.html))
- **Blocks** are specified with the prefix `In`  or by using the keyword `block`([supported blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html))
- **Categories** may be specified with the optional prefix `Is` or using keyword `general_category` or `gc`([supported categories](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html))
- **Binary properties** are specified with the prefix `Is` ([supported properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html))

[REFERECE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/unicode.html)

Comment: I am doing this with text AA and it returns true!

Comment: @Campiador thats strange..can you paste the code you are using to match?

Comment: OK may bad, I was using P instead of p, out of negligence.